# How to use ASTRewrite for inserting/updating body of the method using JDT?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I want to write code inside the method using JDT's ASTRewrite. I tried using ASTRewrite but its not working. Kindly help. Sample code of my ASTRewrite is below:

```java
public void implementMethod(MethodDeclaration methodToBeImplemented) {
    astOfMethod = methodToBeImplemented.getAST(); 
    ASTRewrite astRewrite = ASTRewrite.create(astOfMethod);

    Block body = astOfMethod.newBlock();
    methodToBeImplemented.setBody(body);

    MethodInvocation newMethodInvocation = astOfMethod.newMethodInvocation();  
    QualifiedName name = astOfMethod.newQualifiedName(astOfMethod  
            .newSimpleName("System"), astOfMethod.newSimpleName("out"));  
    newMethodInvocation.setExpression(name);  
    newMethodInvocation.setName(astOfMethod.newSimpleName("println"));

    ExpressionStatement expressionStatement = astOfMethod.newExpressionStatement(newMethodInvocation);  
    body.statements().add(expressionStatement);

    astRewrite.set(oldBody, MethodDeclaration.BODY_PROPERTY, body, null);

    ctcObj.document = new Document(ctcObj.source);
    edit = astRewrite.rewriteAST(ctcObj.document, null);
    try {
        edit.apply(ctcObj.document);
    } catch (MalformedTreeException e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried using different types of ASTRewrite.set() but it generates either compile time error saying illegal parameters or run time exceptions.

Comment: Next time, please clean your code before you post.  I cleaned it this time, but it is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more step: Write to file. edit(apply) does not write to file.
Example see:
[Rewrite method incorrectly rewrite change to ICompilationUnit the second rewrite update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834151/rewrite-method-incorrectly-rewrite-change-to-icompilationunit-the-second-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

(As the declaration of `oldBody` is missing I'm assuming in the following a correct declaration.)

---

The following line must be removed:

```
methodToBeImplemented.setBody(body);
```

With the above line you manually changing a node which should be a target of `ASTRewrite`. Usually that is not recommended.

Next, your call

```
astRewrite.set(oldBody, MethodDeclaration.BODY_PROPERTY, body, null);
```

fails because the target node (1st parameter) and target node property (2nd parameter) must be matching regarding the node class. But in your case it is `Block (oldBody)` and `MethodDeclaration (BODY_PROPERTY)`. A proper call is:

```
astRewrite.set(methodToBeImplemented, MethodDeclaration.BODY_PROPERTY, body, null);
```

---

An alternative solution to `ASTRewrite.set()` would be this call:

```
astRewrite.replace(oldBody, body, null);
```